# Changing Offerup Search Radius

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently looking to increase the offerup search radius beyond the 50 miles it limits you to, I'm trying to do a world wide search but I don't want to have to save like 100 zip codes to do that.

https://offerup.com/search?radius=50&delivery_param=p&q=SPONGEBOB

At first I thought this would be as simple as changing the radius to above 50 to whatever desired number, I was wrong. When making it a number like 100 for example it just reverts to having 30 miles as the max search distance.

With that I went into the source code and found `"p","radius":"30"`, I thought I had figured things out so I went to inspect element to try to change this number and it seemingly disappeared. I'm unsure of what to do next due to my limited knowledge on HTML and Javascript, if you could help me I'd greatly appreciate it.

To find `"p","radius":"30"` in the source code I just did **CTRL + F** and looked up **"p",** and went down till I found this.